# Not able to open files in visual studio after debugging application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on an ASP.net mvc project in Visual Studio 2012. Came across this issue, which is incredibly annoying when debugging my application. Say that I have n number of files open in my editor whenever I build and start a debug-session using F5. Ok, so the editor closes all the open documents as usual, and I do my debuggig tasks. Now; when I stop debugging and want to re-open the files that I had open earlier, I'm not allowed to do so. Nothing whatsoever happens when I click these files, until I restart VS2012.

If I close all of my open documents before debugging, opening them after works fine and the way it's supposed to. Also, this is the case for all of my new or existing projects. I run with ReSharper 7.1.2 installed.
Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually stopping the debugger? If you just close some windows and things you can end up in a state where Visual Studio is still debugging, and the only indication is the toolbars etc (depending on what your debug UI configuration is).

Comment: Yeah, I've stopped the debugger. I've tried first stopping the debugger, then closing the application (in my case - the web page) and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I found that [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) was causing the problem.

Whenever I tried to check in (or out) the code, it caused some exception.

I have no clue, why this prohibited me from opening files after debug but it works after removing AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 1):

To stop ALL files from being closed after debugging simply go to

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset Settings
```

This will fix this bug, I have the old settings saved that caused this error but I am unsure what specifically causes it within the settings. After frustratingly searching around for a clear answer to this problem I hope this helps others that might have this issue.

*Note, I also had your error in my instance of VS 2012 but had neither of your extensions. I would propose that uninstalling your extension removed the setting causing the error.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried cleaning the solution?

Go to `Build` then click `Clean` solution

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue as well. I wasn't able to solve it. In my case, the file was open but it was invisible. After debugging again with the file still open but "invisible" I got an error that the `file doesn't exist` when I navigated to the page (I faced this issue while working on an ASP.NET project).

I recommend reinstalling [VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/), in case you've messed with all the debugging and window settings.